# Power Automate flow to update file properties from list using a Common ID

Tags: power-automate

I have set up the following flow to try and update file properties when an Item is modified in another list:

[image]

Following a YouTube video where I have had success updating one list from another: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYsMNoc7aPY

I am attempting to do the same but this time updating a file instead of a list.

between them, they share a column called commonID. This is separate from the ID column which is automatically generated and not common between the list and library.

So the steps are:

1. A list item is modified on a list called Metrics.
2. Get Items from a Library called Profiles
3. Filter the Document library so that CommonID of get items is equal to the common id of the list when an item is created or modified
4. Update the file properties.

There appears to be an issue with the filter step, in that it is returning [].

[image]

Strangely when I set the commonID = to itself it always works but adds the status of the original list to each item in the document library.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Example when it does work:

[image]

So why randomly? Some I can understand as the file was being used, but for lots they haven't been opened for a while...

Dont understand it

other clue:

[image]

Comment: Can you click on edit in advanced mode link of the Filter array action and share the expression in this thread? Can you also check both the outputs of the Get items and the trigger action to check if both CommonID field and values are available?

Comment: hi there: So as an update it has started semi-working but I just don understand it. 

`@equals(item()?['CommonID'], triggerOutputs()?['body/CommonID'])`

that the advanced mode expression for the filter. 

When I try to do it myself it fails. but when I updated a column for all of the items in the list, it started to update the documents, somewhat randomly as its not perfectly capture what the original list says in the document metadata.

Comment: Btw, you can also filter with the Filter Query field in the Get items. This way you don't have to use a Filter Array action and the Get Items will also be quicker. It looks like currently it takes a while for your data to be retrieved in the Get items action (5 minutes) and I also see a HTTP 429 response, which is throttling. Use something like `CommonID eq '@{triggerOutputs()?['body/CommonID']}'`

Comment: Testing now, will update

Comment: Seems to be a much bigger improvement, thank you.

Comment: @Expiscornovus if you would like to submit as answer I would be happy to select. I appreciate it seems trivial now but I think its likely something that is useful to others.

Comment: Great to hear it helps you. I just submitted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also filter with the Filter Query field in the Get items. This way you don't have to use a Filter Array action and the Get Items will also be quicker.

It looks like currently it takes a while for your data to be retrieved in the Get items action (5 minutes) and I also see a HTTP 429 response, which is throttling.

Use something like `CommonID eq '@{triggerOutputs()?['body/CommonID']}'`